# Universal method of opening some sort of BASH shell on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shell

I was wondering if there was a universal method of opening a BASH terminal on all (or atleast most) linux distributions, using keyboard shortcuts.

- This can be accessing the `TTY` using the `f1..12` keys,
- things like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (like `Ubuntu`).

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: `ctrl+alt+f[1-6]` shoudl give you a virtual terminal - some distros set up log displays on one of them, some installers only have one or two available

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-T` is not really from the distro, it is a desktop manager shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

No - there is no (nor cannot be) any "universal" means of creating a terminal shell invoked by keystrokes.  Keep in mind that a terminal running bash (or some other shell) is not even dependent on having a windowing system (such as X) running, so any short-cuts will be necessarily be dependent on whatever window-manager/desktop you happen to be running.